# Selling non-dividend for dividend stocks

Tags: stocks, dividends, dividend-reinvestment, rsu

H all,

Few years ago , I received from my previous employer several hundred RSU,  all managed by ETrade. since then all have already got Vested. I never sold neither bought any, in other words, I never had any concrete benefits out of this, though the stock price increased steadily every year.

I would like to sell these stocks and build (for the very long run...) a dividend growth portfolio, my questions are:

1. Is selling Vested RSU is the same as selling a regular stock?
2. I'm not a US citizen, my account is in ETrade and my stocks are of a US company, what pre arrangements I need to take to avoid tax issues?

thanks,

Comment: What country are you in? There will likely be tax in your home country.

Comment: Israel. I already fill the W8BEN.

Answer (score 2):

> Is selling Vested RSU is the same as selling a regular stock?

Yes. Your basis (to calculate the gain) is what you've been taxed on when the RSUs vested. Check your payslips/W2 for that period, and the employer should probably have sent you detailed information about that.

> I'm not a US citizen, my account is in ETrade and my stocks are of a
>   US company, what pre arrangements I need to take to avoid tax issues?

You will pay capital gains taxes on the sale in Israel. Depending on where you were when you earned the stocks and what taxes you paid then - it may open additional issues with the Israeli tax authority. Check with an Israeli tax adviser/accountant.

Comment: And check if Israel has double taxation treaty you may need to file a wben8